# PowerDNS authoritative and recursor, replication setup

Tags: domain-name-system, powerdns

We have a primary and secondary in their own respective data centers using pdns 'native' replication - it's not doing axfr but rather a direct SQL replication.

This is a private network hosting DNS for some internal infrastructure. It hosts authoritative zones and recurses upstream to a domain controller.

pdns-recursor sits on port 53.
pdns-server sits on 5300.

Whenever I add a zone, I have to add the domain to the forward-zones-recurse (will have to add to recursor.d/ soon) on both primary and secondary pdns instances.

We have pdnsadmin gui on the primary so if someone adds a domain ther and they don't know anything else, they're going to get confused.

I can automate the creation of a zone to update everything, but I'm curious if this is the best setup or if I'm missing something. I get that resolver and recursor are two different things but this still seems different than BIND and a little bizarre.